# Persisting list items in ListAdapter on configurationChanges with setRetainInstance

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I have an `ArrayListAdapter`. On configuration changes the list is not recreated. I would like to persist the list. I have used `onSaveInstance()` method to do this but I know it is not the best place where to store this kind of data.

A more appropriate method would be `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` but it has been deprecated in favor of `setRetainInstance()` in a Fragment. I don't understand how the setRetainInstance in Fragment could replace onRetainNonConfigurationInstance for the above situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand how the setRetainInstance in Fragment could replace onRetainNonConfigurationInstance for the above situation.

If your fragment is dynamically added via a `FragmentTransaction`, and you call `setRetainInstance(true)` on that fragment, when the device undergoes a configuration change, Android will retain the existing fragment instance and reuse it in the newly-created activity. In all other cases, Android will discard the original fragment and create a brand-new fragment instance to go with the brand-new activity instance. If your fragment instance is retained, all of its data members are retained, so your `ListView` will be retained, along with its configured `ListAdapter` and everything else.

So, the key question is: is the data in your ArrayList part of your data model, or not?

If it is part of your data model, you probably should be persisting it somewhere (database, JSON file, etc.), and then you can simply reload it in the brand-new fragment instance.

If it is not part of your data model, then `setRetainInstance(true)`, or possibly `onSaveInstanceState()`, would be appropriate options.

Comment: so, if I have data downloaded from network, the right steps are: save it to the database and then load from db? I used to jump the saving to db step and save it with onSaveInstanceState. Very wrong? Thanks

Comment: @Matroska: "so, if I have data downloaded from network, the right steps are: save it to the database and then load from db?" -- if you do not want to have to download the data again right away, you should consider saving it to disk in one form or another. For example, if the user runs your app tomorrow, and the data should not be any different, why download it again? "Very wrong?" -- the `Bundle` for `onSaveInstanceState()` should not be very large, as it gets copied and passed between processes. "Instance state" is usually for stuff the *user* has done in the activity, not its backing data.

Comment: I have put an object serializer into onDestroy method and a loader in onCreate. My question is...doesn't the onSaveInstanceState do the same thing?

Comment: @Matroska: First, `onSaveInstanceState()` is not always used, and so it is no replacement for a real persistent data model. Second, `onSaveInstanceState()` does not persist its `Bundle` -- it is held in RAM, either in your process or an OS process.

Comment: @CommonsWare I know this is old, but I'm intrigued by your comment that " the Bundle for onSaveInstanceState() should not be very large, as it gets copied and passed between processes. "Instance state" is usually for stuff the user has done in the activity, not its backing data." -- I believe it, but where are you drawing this from and where can I read more about this? Specifically, I have used instance state to persist my view's model and I want to know how to approach this better.

Comment: @JonWillis: "I believe it, but where are you drawing this from" -- the fact that the state survives process termination (e.g., user presses HOME, your process gets terminated, user returns to you via recent-tasks list). By definition, it cannot be in your old process, and it had to get to the new process somehow. Moreover, the point behind `Bundle` is that it is `Parcelable`, for passing across process boundaries. Otherwise, we'd just use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` (perhaps under a shorter name).

Comment: Ah, yes. In that case of termination, my controllers will reach out to their data sources for fresh or disk cached data. Before they are terminated though, I try to retain that data in the controllers' memory across configuration and lifecycle changes to reduce excessive network and disk access and to speed up time-to-view for the user. It is far from perfect...