# Move between different tabs without create all the times the view

Tags: android, tabs, view, android-fragments

I have a doubt about my program.

I have 3 tabs in the action bar (made with fragments), each one shows a different view. These views have a lot of information that they collect from a database to show charts. The problem is that the ammount of information is quite big for read it everytime I change from one tab to another.
The question: 
Is there any way to create each view only once and then just move between them?

The Activity:

```
    String label1 = "one day";              
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();           
    tab.setText(label1);                
    TabListener<Tab1Fragment> tl = new TabListener<Tab1Fragment>(this, label1, Tab1Fragment.class);     
    tab.setTabListener(tl);                     
    actionBar.addTab(tab);                  
    String label2 = "two days";
    tab = actionBar.newTab();
    tab.setText(label2); 
    TabListener<Tab2Fragment> tl2 = new TabListener<Tab2Fragment>(this, label2, Tab2Fragment.class);
    tab.setTabListener(tl2);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);        
    String label3 = "three days";
    tab = actionBar.newTab();
    tab.setText(label3);
    TabListener<Tab3Fragment> tl3 = new TabListener<Tab3Fragment>(this, label3, Tab3Fragment.class);
    tab.setTabListener(tl3);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

The tab listener class:

```
private class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    private Fragment fragment;              
    private final Activity activity; 
    private final String tag; 
    private final Class<T> classT; 

    public TabListener(Activity activityTab, String tagTab, Class<T> classTab) { 
        activity = activityTab; 
        tag = tagTab; 
        classT = classTab; 
    } 

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {  
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (fragment == null) {                                            
           fragment = Fragment.instantiate(activity, classT.getName()); 
           ft.add(android.R.id.content, fragment, tag); 
       } else { 
           ft.attach(fragment);                            }
    } 

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.detach(fragment);
    }
```

And one of the fragments (the 3 are the same, only change the R.layout.**):

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    setRetainInstance(true);
    return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Each fragment can retain its state. Call `setRetainInstance(true)` in the fragment constructor.

Then you should fetch the data only if it has not already been fetched (if your store you data in a List, set that list to null in the constructor, create and fill it when you fetch data, and in the onStart method, if the list is null, fetch the data. Else, do nothing).

See also: [Persisting list items in ListAdapter on configurationChanges with setRetainInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735514/persisting-list-items-in-listadapter-on-configurationchanges-with-setretaininsta)

Comment: I added in the three fragments and it didn't work. 
I will edit with some of code.